# How do I filter out empty values in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, post

I am posting to an API, and if no values are entered in the `pricing` form fields, I want to send an empty array.

I have tried using the filter method but when I make the post request it sends an array with an empty object i.e. `[{}]`

My state is:

```
title: "",
ticketing: "",                      // is equal to 0 (paid) or 1 (free)
pricing: [
           {
            price: "",
            currency: "",
            ticketLabel: ""
           }
         ],
```

When ticketing is equal to 1, no values will be inputted for `price`, `currency` and `ticketLabel`.

This is my submit function:

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const info = {
      title: this.state.title,
      ticketing: this.state.ticketing,
      price: [
               {
                 currency: this.state.currency,
                 price: this.state.price,
                 label: this.state.ticketLabel
               }
             ].filter(token => Object.keys(token).length != 0)
      }
```

And I post it as

```
axios
  .post(`https://www.diaspora100.com/api/v1/public/events/`, {
    info,
})
```

Currently, this posts as:

```
price: [{}]
  0: {}
```

I would like it to post as:

```
price: []
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `filter(token => Object.keys(token).value != 0)` object.keys returns a array and it's doesn't have property named `value`

Comment: `Object.keys(token)` is an array and `Object.keys(token).value` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant length, I have updated my question

Comment: `When ticketing is equal to 1, no values will be inputted for price, currency and ticketLabel` so keys will still exists so the `object.keys(toke).length` will always be greater `0`

Comment: Length will always be 3, since there are 3 keys in your object, no matter if they're empty. Your filter is wrong, but your whole object doesn't make much sense... Maybe you should update your question providing more information on what you're trying to represent/achieve...

Comment: You need to do something like this `filter(token => Object.values(token).some(v=> v != ''))`

Answer (score 2):

> When ticketing is equal to 1, no values will be inputted for price,
>   currency and ticketLabel

maybe you want something like this

```
const info = {
      title: this.state.title,
      ticketing: this.state.ticketing,
      price: this.state.ticketing !== 1 ? [
               {
                 currency: this.state.currency,
                 price: this.state.price,
                 label: this.state.ticketLabel
               }
      ] : []
}
```

Comment: since ticketing is boolean value so you can have it as `this.state.ticketing && object || []` anyways your answer is spot on +1

Answer (score 0):

in the filter part of the price you can try this

```js
<price-array>.filter(token => token.price.length > 0)
```